# Returning the index of an item clicked in a tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, selection

I'm trying to get tkinter to return the index of an item clicked in listbox. Here's my code.

```
def fileSelection(self):
    selection = listbox.curselection
    print(selection)

listbox.bind("<Button-1>", fileSelection)
```

Right now it prints

> bound method Listbox.curselection of tkinter.Listbox object at 0x00320E30

no matter what item is clicked on. If I change the code to include a button like this:

```
button = Button(text=u"test", command=OnButtonClick)

def OnButtonClick():
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    print(selection)
```

and select the Listbox item, then click the button, it will print the index of the selected item, as expected, but that's an extra step I don't want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def fileSelection(self):
    selection = listbox.curselection
    print(selection)
```

Looks like you forgot the parentheses.

```
def fileSelection(self):
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    print(selection)
```

Comment: Christ... can I delete this? *slinks away*

Answer (score -1):

According to [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm), polling the widget allows you to do on click updates.

```
self.current = None
self.listbox = Listbox(self)
self.listbox.pack()
self.poll()

def poll(self):
    now = self.listbox.curselection()
    if now != self.current:
        self.list_has_changed(now)
        self.current = now
    self.after(250, self.poll)

def list_has_changed(self, selection):
    print "selection is", selection
```

Comment: That effbot page is _waaaayyyy_ out of date. The GUI will fire an event when the selection changes ( `<<ListobxSelect>>`) Regardless, your solution doesn't answer the actual question that was asked, it just works around it.